# Prove $\{0^k10^k10^k1 \in \{0,1\}^* \mid k \geq 0 \}$ is not context free

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, regular-language, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I'm practising for my CS exam and got stuck on this problem

$$ \{0^k10^k10^k1 \in \{0,1\}^*\mid k ≥ 0\}. $$

I think I have good start however I don't know how to proceed. I assume the L is context free, and that pumping lemma applies with some pumping length $n$.

$$|w| = 3k,\quad w = uvxyz$$

Since $|vxy| \geq n$ it can't contain all characters. Considering $uv^2xy^2z$ would end up having more than $3$ zeros if anything is pumped in. However I'm not sure how t o move from here. Is that enough of a proof?

Comment: This is basically the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330377/showing-the-following-language-is-not-contex-free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof that $L$ is not regular**

Assume that $L$ is regular, then there exists $p$ such that for all $|w|\geq p\:, \exists x,y,z, \: y\neq \varepsilon \text{ and } \forall k, \: xy^kz \in L$.

Take $n>p$ (we're not going to be subtle here. Then $w=0^n10^n10^n1 \in L$, so we can slice it into three part $x,y,z$. Let us consider $y$

- if $1 \in y$ then $xy^kz \not\in L$, for it would contains to many $1$'s
- otherwise, $y=0^d$ for some $d$, but then $xy^kz = 0^{n_1} 1 0^{n_2} 1 0^{n_3} 1 \not\in L$ because the $n_i$ won't be equal anymore.

Hence we cannot apply the pumping lemma for regular languages, $L$ is therefore not regular.

---

**Proof that $L$ is not context-free**

as suggested by @posilon, we can also prove that the language is not context free by applying [this pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages)

There exists a $p$ such that, if $|w|\geq p$ then we can slice $w = uvwxy$
such that:

- 1. $|vx| \geq 1$
- 2. $|vwx| \leq p$
- 3. $uv^n wx^n y \in L$ for all $n \geq 0$.

here again, let us consider the number of $1$'s in $vx$

- if $1 \in vx$ then $uv^n wx^n y  \not\in L$, for it would contains to many $1$'s
- otherwise, $v=0^d, x=0^{d'}$ for some $d,d'$, but then $uv^n wx^n y  = 0^{n_1} 1 0^{n_2} 1 0^{n_3} 1 \not\in L$ because the $n_i$ won't be equal anymore.

Hence we cannot apply the pumping lemma for context-free languages, $L$ is therefore not context-free.

Comment: I think the OP wants to show that $L$ is not context-free, so the [pumping lemma for context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) will be useful.

Comment: You are welcome! I think that in your second proof, two occurrences of $y$ should be replaced by $v$ (at $1 \in yx$ and $y=0^d$).

Comment: you're obviously right, thanks a lot

Comment: Yes sorry, I wanted to prove that L it's not context free, updated.